# Diaplay a popup window on parent fragment

Tags: android

I have a tab activity.
1 of its tab it contains a listView which contains fragment items.
I have a button on these list items (which are fragments), and I want whenerver I click it to show a popup window.
Unfortunatly I can see the popup, and I assume it's because the display ot the list item is too small.
I would actually like to see it on the activity which contains the list.

Any ideas?

edit:
**The dialog:**

**public class CancelRunPupUp extends DialogFragment {**

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.cancelRunTitle))
            .setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.AreYouSure))
            .setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.yes), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.no), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
    return dialog;
}
```

}

**The button which calls this dialog:**

In public class RowInHomeTab extends Fragment:

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_row_in_home_tab, container, false);

    ImageButton cancelRun = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.cancelRunButton);

    cancelRun.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            CancelRunPupUp dialog = new CancelRunPupUp();
            dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "cancelRunDialog");
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

RowInHomeTab  is an item in a listView which is placed in a tabActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Dialog Fragment to popup the window ....

```
                DFragment dFragment = new DFragment();
            // Show DialogFragment
            dFragment.show(fm, "Dialog Fragment");
```

Comment: I tried to use it too, but still when I click the button on the item list the Dialog doesn't appear.

Comment: let me know where this button exists ? in list view as item or as sub item in the list view ... mean the layout you are inflating the button is defined there ?

Answer (score 0):

Might be al little bit "oversized" but you can use System Alert:

```
alert.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
```

But this requires

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

edit:
ok, seems that you already set the type to SYSTEM_ALERT, then I have no other idea but store the Context of the activity you want the Dialog to be shown and use this global var instead of getActivity() in your Dialog Class.
But this is very sticky...
The activity containing the List view needs:

```
public static Context main_ctx;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    main_ctx = this;
    [...]
```

And your Dialog Fragment:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder([YOUR CLASS NAME].main_ctx);
```

edit:

**Last try**

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               CancelRunPupUp dialog = new CancelRunPupUp();
               dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "cancelRunDialog");  
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you be more specific where should I put the: alert.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);     and also what does it do?

Comment: I thought u are using an AlertDialog, if not, please provide the code of your CancelRunPopup Class

Comment: i am. and I added it.

Comment: But i'm sure you will find an Activity containing this Fragment... Just search for the right context and provide this context to the DialogBuilder.